# Autozoom webview scrollview in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, url, uiscrollview, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I want to autozoom my webview's scrollview from my code .

My desired output is [image]

But I am getting this 
[image]

I am sharing my code please help me out.

```
 webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill | UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit|UIViewContentModeScaleToFill
        ;
        webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"increaseMaxZoomFactor()"];
        [webView.scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(300, 300, 300, 300) animated:YES];
```

Please help me out 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this one line work the tricks for me

```
 webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
```